# how to return arraylist of custom object from web service?

Tags: java, web-services, client, rmi

How can i get array list of custom object from web service?

I define a method that returns a list like this : `ArrayList<Car> getVehicle() {...}`

But in client ws, I receive an ArrayList of objects...

It seems I can't cast it even by copying custom class to client jar file of my applet, like serialized object...

How can i do that?

Comment: i am using netBeans web service that use JAXB and JAX-WS2.1 lib, i that right answer? what i must to do? i am a beginner in english, so sorry... :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have to cast objects in arraylist at webservice's client end. Did you verify that in .wsdl file you mention proper return type of webservice method?
please publish the solution if you already solved this issue.

Comment: i solve it by a method like serialize object and RMI , i cant find solution at ws
if you want to see code , i can show u?

Answer (score 0):

Likewise annotationfree, you can get element even no annotation

```
ArrayList entries = new ArrayList(number); 
//get,startloop 
  entries.add(new LabelValueElement(
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by just converting the ArrayList into **Object[]** by using **ArrayList's toArray()** method it will convert into Object[] and it can be used as **bject[] getVehicle() {...}** where you call it traverse his array and cast into Car object.

Answer (score -1):

Is this an option:

```
List<Vehicule> getVehicule() {...}
```

Does it change anything?